# The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#

I followed the suggestion around this web site to made the following method:

```
public static T? GetElementValue<T>(this XElement xElement, string s) 
    where T : struct, IComparable
{
     var result = new Nullable<T>();

     try
     {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || s.Trim().Length > 0 || xElement.IsEmpty)
            return result;

         var element = xElement.Element(s);

         if (element == null || element.IsEmpty)
             return result;

         var conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
         result = (T)conv.ConvertFrom(element.Value);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          ex.Message.WriteAsError();
     }

     return result;
}
```

but when I try to use it with a `string` I still get the following error:
The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

Someone can tell me why?
Thx

Comment: A couple of things to note: 1) Instead of checking for `string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || s.Trim().Length > 0`, instead just check for `String.IsNullOrWhitespace(s)`. 2) You should check the variable `xElement` to see if it is null before using it (because it can be). 3) If a method is going to swallow up exceptions, generally you want to make it `bool TryGetElementValue<T>(..., out T? result) { ... }`, that is the preferred pattern (return bool, name it with *Try*, and have an out parameter).

Comment: You probably want to restrict on the `IConvertible` interface rather than `IComparable` from what I can see of your code.

Comment: what about I wanna use the same method to return a Nullable object?

q.GetElementValue<int>("myIntCanBeNull");

Comment: @m-y in this case I have to change totally my function but I agree with u. Could u write an example?
And with out T?, I got Only non-nullable value type could be underlying of "System.Nullable"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have restricted your `T` parameter by

```
where T : struct
```

The `struct` restriction means that only value types can be supplied for `T`. `string` (more precisely, [`System.String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx)) however, is a class, a reference type.

Removing that restriction will not be quite trivial, as you use `T` as `T?`, i.e. a nullable `T`. [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) in turn only accepts value types.

You will have to decide on whether you want to allow reference types - if you want to restrict `T` to reference types, use the `class` constraint instead of `struct` (and drop the `?` from `T?`, as reference types are always nullable on their own). If you want to allow both value and reference types, you cannot make a nullable version of `T`. If you need all of these, please extend your description of the circumstances so we can help you find a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

because you're restricting T to a value type - `where T : struct, IComparable`, whereas string is a reference type.

Comment: Someone just press button randomly

Answer (score 3):

a string is not a value type, it is an immutable reference type so it violates the generic constraint you have where T must be a `struct`.

Take a look at the [`string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx) type documentation for more details about `string`.